Intel RealSense installation on Raspberry Pi
I am currently trying to install the intel RealSense viewer on my raspberry pi 4 running the default Raspberry Pi OS.
The problem is when I run
~/protobuf/python $ python setup.py build --cpp_implementation

I get a long (error)
The issue is due to the invalid use of a incomplete type PyFrameObject.
Additionally, deprecated functions like PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords are being used.
How can I fix it?
I could change the source code. But I dont want that. What else could I try?
